# How to filter dataframe with same column name?

Tags: r, filter

I am reading one text file which has redundant column names.

file.txt

```
A  B  B  E  E
2  2  4  4  5
3  4  5  6  8
```

I want to Keep columns which has B and E as column name. but when i read the file

```
rt<-read.table("file.txt",header=TRUE)

  A B B.1 E E.1
  1 2 4   4 5
  2 4 5   6 8
```

Can i use regular expression while filtering dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grep` to select the columns with `names` that start with either `B` or `E`.  By default, `data.frame` do not allow to have to duplicate column names, and it is infact very useful in many ways.

```
 df1[grep("^(B|E)", names(df1))]
 #  B B.1 E E.1
 #1 2   4 4   5
 #2 4   5 6   8
```

However, we could read the dataset with `check.names=FALSE` in the `read.table/read.csv`,  if we need to keep the duplicate column names, but I would not recommend to do that as it will create a lot of confusion while subsetting.  Without using `check.names`, the `read.table` calls the `make.unique` to get `unique` column names even if there are duplicate column names.

Answer (score 1):

```
Another way of coding for the same   
 rt[!grepl("^A",colnames(rt))]
      B B.1 E E.1
      2   4 4   5
      4   5 6   8
```